# Installing node module locally using sudo fails in High Sierra

Tags: npm, node-modules, macos-high-sierra

While installing node module using `sudo npm install` locally will get Error: EACCES: permission denied in some node modules like phantomjs and node-sass that using script to install. This is local installation of npm not globally.

npm 5.5.1
macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Is there any issue with High Sierra? as in Sierra is working fine.

Comment: Why sudo ? You should not use sudo to install npm packages. If you need sudo it means that you installation of node and npm was done with wrong rights and you should probably reinstall it properly.

Comment: @ChrisR but when in Sierra is working fine using sudo. Why is failing in High Sierra. For global installation is working without sudo and it's only with node module that using script to install. Other node module it's working.